# Rails: Google Chart only loads after reloaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts

I include Google chart in my view page, but the problem is that I always need to reload the view page to get the Google chart displayed. The Google chart never displayed itself when I click link and go to this view page.

Is this happening because I'm using Ruby on Rails?

How do I get it to displayed in the first time when I go in to that page.

The below code is my view that include the Google chart:

```
<!-- Append content in the head tag in layout view-->
<% content_for :for_head do %>
  <title>Analysis</title>

  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><!--Load the Google JSAPI library-->
  <script type="text/javascript">//<!--Load the Google Visualization and chart libraries-->
    // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    //Immediately after calling google.load(), your code should call google.setOnLoadCallback(my_handler), a Google JSAPI function that calls your handler as soon as all the libraries are loaded.
    //Your handler function should create and define the chart.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // My handler function is called drawChart
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {

      //First, create a DataTable
      var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dt.addColumn('string', 'Book Color'); //the first column is about the color of the book
      dt.addColumn('number', 'boooks');     // second column is about the number of the book that has corresponding color
      dt.addRows([
        ['Yellow',3],
        ['Red',4],
        ['Blue',8],
        ['Green',13],
        ['Purple',2],
        ['Brown',4],
        ['Violet',9],
        ['Orange',10],
        ['White',7],
        ['Black',2]
      ]);

      //Set chart options, inlcuding title and dimension
      var opt = {
        'title': 'How many books do I have?',
        'is3D':true
      };

      //Instantiates a chart and specify which container does this chart will go to
      var ch = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));  //Here we instantiate a chart as a PieChart that will go into the container whose id is named chart_div_1

      //Using the above chart instance, draw a chart according to the datatable and options we defined earlier
      ch.draw(dt, opt);
  }
  </script>
<% end %>

<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div_1" style="width:800; height:600"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<!-- Append content in the head tag in layout view-->
<% content_for :for_head do %>
  <title>Analysis</title>
```

Moved your element here.

```
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div_1" style="width:800; height:600"></div>


  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><!--Load the Google JSAPI library-->
  <script type="text/javascript">//<!--Load the Google Visualization and chart libraries-->
 function showGraph() {
    // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    //Immediately after calling google.load(), your code should call google.setOnLoadCallback(my_handler), a Google JSAPI function that calls your handler as soon as all the libraries are loaded.
    //Your handler function should create and define the chart.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // My handler function is called drawChart
    // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {

      //First, create a DataTable
      var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dt.addColumn('string', 'Book Color'); //the first column is about the color of the book
      dt.addColumn('number', 'boooks');     // second column is about the number of the book that has corresponding color
      dt.addRows([
        ['Yellow',3],
        ['Red',4],
        ['Blue',8],
        ['Green',13],
        ['Purple',2],
        ['Brown',4],
        ['Violet',9],
        ['Orange',10],
        ['White',7],
        ['Black',2]
      ]);

      //Set chart options, inlcuding title and dimension
      var opt = {
        'title': 'How many books do I have?',
        'is3D':true
      };

      //Instantiates a chart and specify which container does this chart will go to
      var ch = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));  //Here we instantiate a chart as a PieChart that will go into the container whose id is named chart_div_1

      //Using the above chart instance, draw a chart according to the datatable and options we defined earlier
      ch.draw(dt, opt);
  }
}
    window.onload = showGraph;
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Also wrap your js code with document on load event

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. How do I wrap my js code with document on load event and why will this work?

Comment: i did it for you in above script check the showGraph function and at the end window.onload is calling it. The reason why you wont get shown on first time is because your DOM is not ready and you ran the JS code before it so it wont be able to find "id="chart_div_1"

Comment: Also i moved div on top

Comment: This is amazing, the chart now display when I first visit the view page. But I want the div to be in the body, not in the head. I tried moved it out of the head, but then it won't load the first time, even if I plce the div at the beginning of the view page (before the head code, line 1 of the view file). Why is that (I thought if I put it at the top it will be read first) and what should I do to have it in the body while letting it load the first time?

Comment: Also "window.onload = showGraph;" should be "window.onload = showGraph();"

Comment: Place div anywhere in body tag and put your Javascripts just before the </body> tag. It will result in a better performance. Also As long as you are using Document On Load Function the position of the div element wont be  an issue.